# Remove adapter defined routing entry

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, routing, packet

I need to remove (or change) the default entry in the routing table for Windows XP, which routes packets with a destination equal to the adapter's address to `localhost`.

The reason for this is I want the PC to be able to send packets to a device (with IP address A) connected to one adapter on the PC with IP address B, even though a second adapter on the PC has IP address A.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the `route` command:

```
C:\Users\John>route /?

Manipulates network routing tables.

ROUTE [-f] [-p] [-4|-6] command [destination]
                  [MASK netmask]  [gateway] [METRIC metric]  [IF interface]

...*snip*
```

to see the current routing table, use `route print`. To delete an entry, use `route delete [ip addr]`.

Comment: That won't work, i did try it; you cannot use the route command to remove a route added by the system, only those added by the route command or dhcp.